# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning - Erro no Cadastro com MongoDB e Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando cadastrar usuários no MongoDB.

O ambiente é windws 8.1 e estou usando também o mongoose, express e axios no backend e o Insomnia para testar o cadastro. Quando tento cadastrar o Node.js me retorna esses erros:

```
(node:252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: location object expected, location array not in correct format
    at Function.create (C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:44:12)
    at toError (C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:150:22)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:265:39
    at handler (C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:971:24)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:496:5
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\SemanaOministack\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:420:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)
(node:252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

O código está assim. Arquivo routes.js:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const Dev = require('./models/Dev');

const routes = Router();

routes.post('/devs', async(request, response) => {
  const {
    github_username,
    techs,
    latitude,
    longitude
  } = request.body;

  const apiResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${github_username}`);

  const {
    name = login, avatar_url, bio
  } = apiResponse.data;

  const techsArray = techs.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim());

  const location = {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
  };

  const dev = await Dev.create({
    github_username,
    name,
    avatar_url,
    bio,
    techs: techsArray,
    location,
  });

  return response.json(dev);
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Arquivo Dev.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PointSchema = require('./utils/PointSchema');

const DevSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    github_username: String,
    bio: String,
    avatar_url: String,
    techs: [String],
    location: {
        type: PointSchema,
        index: '2dsphere',
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dev', DevSchema);
```

Arquivo index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://omnistack:omnistack@cluster0-pka8b.mongodb.net/week10?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use(routes);

app.listen(3333);
```

Arquivo PointSchema.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true,
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = PointSchema;
```

Já tentei olhar na documentação mas não consegui tratar os erros. O IP está liberado. Coloquei lá no mongo 0.0.0.0. O cadastro funcionava normalmente até eu adicionar o "location", na linha 27, arquivo routes.js. Se comentar a linha, executa normalmente. O problema está ali, mas não faço ideia do que teno que fazer para resolver.

Comment: Poste seu Código para que alguém possa te ajudar.

Comment: Por favor substitua as imagens por texto e não esqueça de formatá-los corretamente.

Comment: tem limitação de IP no mongodb? tiver coloca 0.0.0.0

Comment: Não tem limitação. IP liberado. 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

O erro está na primeira linha:

> location object expected, location array not in correct format

Altera tua model apenas para fins de teste:

```
const DevSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    github_username: String,
    bio: String,
    avatar_url: String,
    techs: [String],
    location: [Number]
});
```

Caso funcione, é teu modelo de coordenadas que precisa ser revisto.

[Aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/armazenando-dados-de-geoposicionamento-com-google-maps-e-mongodb/31864) tem um tutorial de como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Olá tive o mesmo problema, o erro e consegui resolver.

O problema é no MongoDB, você precisa acessar o banco de dados pela web, e na parte de **indexes**, vão ter 3 indexes. Deixe apenas os indexes ID que é o **default** e o outro chamado **location_2dsphere** o que não for isso pode apagar.